# No include file for fortran library

Tags: apt, compiling, shared-library, fortran

I need to build a Fortran program that uses (among others) the library netcdf, which I downloaded using apt-get (my computer is on Ubuntu 20.04). Installing the library worked, the share object files for the library are there, but upon running the makefile of the program I need to install, it doesn't work because it doesn't find the include files for this library. I am not familiar with Fortran, is it a common thing to need the include file in this case? As far as I know (or rather experienced), linking such libraries doesn't require include files in C++. I assume if I needed them normally, I should have had got them when installing the library.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You have to install necessary [NetCDF development package for fortran](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/netcdf-fortran) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install libnetcdff-dev
```

and then retry building your application.

Comment: The general rule of thumb to get the development header files is to append `-dev` to the name of the library package.